# How do I iterate through a list in my View?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

In my view I'm returning some results from a webservice and storing them in a session variable.

Here's the Session Storage Method:

```
//AreaSummary[] is a reference to the webservice reference gubbins

 public AreaSummary[] Results
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Results != null)
                {
                    return this.Results;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Results"] != null)
                    {
                        this.Results = 
                                   (AreaSummary[])HttpContext.Current.Session["Results"];
                                   return this.Results;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

            set
            {
                this.Results= null;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Results"] = value;
            }
        }
```

In the Controller I set the results to this session to save having to push the request again and again (for paging).

So I set the session to the result set:

```
this.mySess.SessionVarss.Results = myservice.SearchForX("stuff");
```

Both the '`Results`' and '`SearchForX`' are of `AreaSummary[]`

```
ViewData["ResultSet"] = this.mySess.SessionVars.Results;
```

I then pass this as `ViewData` in the controller without an issue and `databind` it to a `repeater` or `datagrid` (that i get).

My first thought was to use a `foreach` loop.

So in the view I was trying:

```
<% foreach (var item in (ViewData["ResultSet"] as List<MyMVC.webservice.AreaSummary[]>))
   { %>    
            <li class="image">
                <img src="<%=item.MainImage.ImageUrl %>" />
            </li>
<% } %>
```

I'm sure the mistake is glaringly obvious to some and I'm missing it through the tunnel-vision.

It compiles fine, but dies with the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The following works:

```
<% 
   placelist.DataSource = ViewData["ResultSet"];
   placelist.DataBind();
%>
<asp:Repeater ID="productlist" runat="server" Visible="true">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <li class="image">
       <img src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MainImage.ImageUrl")%>" />
   </li>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I'd prefer to use a `foreach` loop as some of the items returned are arrays and with the `repeater` I'll end up doing more.

### Proper Solution

The better solution in the end was to pass the data to the view:

```
return View("index",SearchResults);
```

Then right click -> `add view`, `index`, `create strongly typed view`, select `webservice.AreaSummary` and `list`.

Comment: How are you using repeaters and datagrids and ASP.NET MVC. And I guess the better question is, WHY?

Comment: The question was aimed at avoiding using repeaters in ASP.NET MVC and thats what the solution allowed. Bit a daft question to add as I do specify that I don't want to use the repeater method. Also on Wekeroad it is shown that these ASP.net controls can be used without issue, and he's right because they do work. But as per the question, I didn't want to travel that road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just posted this example in another question. Try something like this,

```
<table class="results" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
<thead class="tablehead">
  <tr> 
    <td width="55px"><b>Country</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>State</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>City</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>Town</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>Postal</b></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% 
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<MY_RESULTS>)ViewData["My_Results"])
    {
        if (count % 2 == 0) { Response.Write("<tr class='even'>"); } else { Response.Write("<tr class='odd'>"); }   
    %>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Country)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.State)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.City)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Town)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Postal)%></td>
        </tr>

    <% count += 1; } %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You my good man were very close to the mark.

foreach(var item in (IEnumerable<mymvc.webservice.AreaSummary>)ViewData["Results"])

It was winging about AreaSummary not being of IEnumerable, so thats just what I needed :o) Thanks, not i dont have to use the repeater

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop looks ok to me although the session and viewdata are not quite the same thing.

Viewdata is stored on the session but anything stored in the session directly has to be referenced from the session in the view. In your case you store the value in Session["Results"] and then try to reference it in the view from ViewData["ResultSet"].

The below looks a bit suspect also.

```
public AreaSummary[] Results
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Results != null)
            {
                return this.Results;
            }
```

Thats a recursive call and it looks a bit wonky. You are referencing the Property getter inside the getter, are you suppose to be referencing a field instead?

Comment: In the control I'm passing the the session back to the view...
 -- 
ViewData["ResultSet"] = this.mySess.SessionVarss.Results;
 -- 
If I use a data-repeater and databind it works fine.